# How to add information to newly created users in swift with firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating a Swift application that has a multistep signup process. The first step actually creates the user and takes their name, age and gender. The second step is for them to add a profile picture along with a special phrase. I tried to use the Firebase Authentication current user technique but that doesn't seem to be working. It seems that the new user is not being set as the current user. Is there a way to accomplish this or a work around to accomplish the goal. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Code *always* belongs in the question itself, not a link to an off-site resource in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your request of Auth().auth().currentUser. If you are accessing it through the completion handler, that could be causing the problem.

What I would suggest is to take `var loggedInUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser` inside of your Next function (or do it when the screen has appeared).